# Diagonal hatchings for SVG-elements

Tags: css, svg

I want to add diagonal colored hatchings to polygons in svg using css.
I know you could use patterns but I am concerned about performance issues when there are too many different patterns that's why I'd rather use css.
I found the repeating-linear-gradient but wasn't able to get it to work on svg elements. Is that possible? If not, are there any other ways in css to add diagonal hatchings to svg elements?

Answer (score 1):

In general browsers do not currently support adding CSS gradients to SVG elements.

You would need to use SVG [`<linearGradient>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#pservers-LinearGradients) elements instead.

Here's an example.

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="hatch1"
                    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10"
                    spreadMethod="repeat">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="transparent"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="transparent"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="green"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="green"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" fill="url(#hatch1)" stroke="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: If you have to declare them in defs to use them, I could also use patterns... I was hoping that there was a way to not dump the entire html full with generated patterns because of performance issues. But if there is no other way, I will have to use patterns...

Comment: Gradients have some advantages over patterns.  Gradients can be drawn directly as a fill by most 2D libraries.  I believe that, in some 2D libraries at least, patterns require extra bitmap buffers to be created.  Thus can be slower and more memory intensive if you have a lot of them.